# Is there any way of developing device(especially printer) drivers for Chrome OS?

Tags: printing, driver, device-driver, google-chrome-os, chromebook

Chromebooks can print documents to printers over Wifi or USB connectivities. However, some printers cannot output from Chrome OS since too old model of printers or no PPD files distributed by manufacturers.

I know Android Apps can run on Chrome OS, so I installed Android printer plugins for [Canon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.canon.android.printservice.plugin) and [Epson](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.epson.mobilephone.android.epsonprintserviceplugin) printers, but seems they don't work in Chrome OS 89 on my Lenovo Chromebook S330.

I want to make drivers for those printers but I can't find information about development of device drivers for Chrome OS.

Is there any way of developing drivers for Chrome OS or not?
I welcome any ideas or hints.